# On dropping element , it is changing its position instead it should remain on the position or coordinates where it is dropped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I am using drag n drop between components. I have achieved that drag n drop functionality of  -
when I drag, it drags a clone and also drops a cloned element but the problem is that when I drop the element (button in my case)

But the issue ocurring is that when I drop the button , it changes its position to on top part of layout and this continues as when I drop other elements they change position and stick horizontally.

I want to achieve that wherever I drop the element it should should stay at that position .

This is a component where I have the buttons placed and from here I have to drag buttons

```
 const { setDraggedButtonId } = useContext(DragContext);
  const { setDraggedButton } = useContext(DragContext);
  // Drag event handler
  const drag = (event, buttonId) => {
    // Set the dragged button using the shared context
    setDraggedButtonId(buttonId);
    const buttonElement = event.target;
    setDraggedButton(buttonElement);
    const buttonClone = buttonElement.cloneNode(true);
    // Set the data to be transferred during the drag
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", buttonId);
    // event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "");
    // event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(buttonClone, 0, 0);
    // event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(buttonClone, -1000, -1000); // For Firefox compatibility
  };

return (
    <div className="w-60 flex-none h-full overflow-y-auto flex flex-col items-start p-2 border-r border-gray-200">
      <div className="font-bold"> {"Events"} </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap bg-yellow-500 text-white px-2 py-1 my-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        {"When "}
        <Icon name="flag" size={15} className="text-green-600 mx-2" />
        {"clicked"}
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap bg-yellow-500 text-white px-2 py-1 my-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
        {"When this sprite clicked"}
      </div>
      <div className="font-bold"> {"Motion"} </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        draggable="true"
        onDragStart={(event) => drag(event, event.target)}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap bg-blue-500 text-white px-2 py-1 my-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
          {"Move 10 steps"}
        </div>
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={rotateCounterclockwise}
        draggable="true"
        onDragStart={(event) => drag(event, event.target)}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap bg-blue-500 text-white px-2 py-1 my-2 text-sm cursor-pointer">
          {"Turn "}
          <Icon name="undo" size={15} className="text-white mx-2" />
          {"15 degrees"}
        </div>
      </button>
)}
```

Now the component where I am dragging the buttons -

```
  const { draggedButton } = useContext(DragContext);

  // Drop event handler
  const drop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const buttonElement = draggedButton;
    const buttonClone = buttonElement.cloneNode(true);
    // const buttonCopy = buttonElement;
    // Append the button to the drop area
    event.target.appendChild(buttonClone);
  };

  // Allow drop event handler
  const allowDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="flex-1 h-full overflow-auto"
      onDragOver={allowDrop}
      onDrop={drop}
    ></div>
  );
```

I have use dragContext component for managing state

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

// Create the drag context
export const DragContext = createContext();

// Create the drag provider component
export const DragProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [draggedButton, setDraggedButton] = useState(null);

  // Set the dragged button
  const setDraggedButtonId = (buttonId) => {
    setDraggedButton(buttonId);
  };

  return (
    <DragContext.Provider value={{ draggedButton, setDraggedButtonId }}>
      {children}
    </DragContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Please provide the solution or the reason as why it is happening .

Thanks in advance
I also tried by getId of button using document.getElementbyId(buttonId) but in this case I am getting null response . I am getting buttonId still the response is null

I tried to drop the clone and then to remain at the coordinates where I dropped but it seems they are going to a specific coordinate.